# Arranging $n$ double-sided cards to produce a given string

Tags: algorithms

Suppose you're given a string $s$ that consists of lowercase alphabetic letters only. The length of the string is $n$. You are also given $n$ cards, which have lowercase alphabetic letters on the front and back. You want to arrange (shuffle and/or flip each card) the $n$ cards in an order that produces the string. You can use either side of a card, but obviously not both.

I am wondering if this problem can be converted to a Hungarian Algorithm problem? We essentially have a bipartite graph here. The left part consists of $n$ nodes representing each character in $s$. For each character in $s$, there is a subset of the $n$ cards that can can be used to create that character.

Can this be turned into a problem that can be solved with the Hungarian algorithm?

Comment: Have you tried carrying out your idea? Where did you get stuck?

Comment: I dont think this can be cast as a hungarian problem as there is no cost for each operation. Also the original problem I presume can be solved in about $O(n \log n)$ time via various sorting methods

Comment: @YuvalFilmus The only idea I have that I know works for certain is to form an adjacency list for each `s[i]` and then do DFS with backtracking. But that algorithm is $O(n! * n)$, I believe. I am trying to see if the Hungarian algorithm works because that would reduce the complexity down to polynomial time.

Comment: @NikosM. Hm, I don't it's possible to solve this problem in sorting, let alone in O(n log n) time? You would sort the string s, I presume, but then, I don't think that makes the problem any easier? Each s[i] can still be formed with some subset of the given cards.

Comment: I was thinking of sorting both the cards (as joint pairs front-back) and the string, and then try a match

Comment: Try reducing this to the problem of finding a perfect matching in a bipartite graph.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus Do you have a source for that representative problem? I haven't really worked with bipartite graphs before.

Comment: You can find it on Wikipedia.